# Capturing and returning datetime when form is submitted in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a basic CRUD style MVC application that has a form that is submitted.  When the form is submitted, I'd like to capture the date and time and return it to my Index View next to the other form data that is presented there. How do I capture the date and time the form is submmitted (posted) and how do I pass this information into my Index View?

***View***

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        ****Need to have a display for Date/Time the form was submitted here ****
    </th>
```

***Controller***

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Applications/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName")] Application application)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Applications.Add(application);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(application);
    }
```

***Model***

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Married { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Unmarried")]
    public bool UnMarried { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
     [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

So basically once the user submits the form I need to pass the current date and time into my Index view and display it underneath the Last Name field.  How can I do this?

Comment: I've added in some of my code to hopefully make this question a bit more clear.  Also reworded the question and added additional information under the code.

Comment: Are you persisting the edit date anywhere or are you only interested in showing this one time (not sure what the purpose of this is)

Comment: The goal is for someone on the back-end of the application to log in and see the submitted customer data along with the date and time it was submitted. I really just need to capture the date and time of form submission and show it in the "Index" view somehow. So next to each customers personal information filled out on the form, there would also be the date and time it was filled out.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You going to have to add a field to your database, then update that each time you save it.

Comment: Ok so I added: public DateTime GetDate { get; set; } to my model.  Problem is I don't know how to capture this and pass it into the View.  I don't wan the customer to manually have to type in the date.

Comment: If you just want server time, not the client's time then you can do it all server side as long as the field is in your model and database.

Comment: Server side would be great, but how!

Comment: Before your `db.Applications.Add(application);` line, just put a line like `application.DateFieldName = DateTime.Now;` where `DateFieldName` is the name you are using.

Comment: When you save the object to the database, set its value to `DateTime.Now`, then render it in the view (can be just `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastEditDate)` rather than a textbox

Answer (score 2):

Added this field to my Model:

```
public DateTime GetDate { get; set; }
```

In Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Customers/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName, GetDate")] Customer customer)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            customer.GetDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(customer);
    }
```

View

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GetDate)
    </td>
```

The Date the customer submitted the form is now displaying!

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the column in your database table to save the DateTime when the customer is inserted in the table? If not, add a column with `DEFAULT GETDATE()` constraint (assuming the database as SQL Server). Now this database column should have the property in your data model and then you can bind this value in your Index view in the same way you did for FirstNAme and LastName properties.

Comment: It looks as though the original poster is user a code first approach rather than database first.